# Reload cell of CollectionView after image is downloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using the library SDWebImage to download the images.

I set the image downloaded to the UICollectionViewCell inside cellForItemAtIndexPath but the image is visible just after scrolling the CollectionView. I think that I must reload that specific cell but no idea how.

Here is the code of UICollectionViewCell

```
[imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]
                               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourPlaceholder.png"]
                                      completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                                          //... completion code here ...
                                          cell.image = imgView.image;
                                          //Reload The cell to see the image downloaded ¿HOW?
                                      }];
```

code of MJCollectionViewCell.m

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // Store image
    self.MJImageView.image = image;

    // Update padding
    [self setImageOffset:self.imageOffset];
}
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: `- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem.

The solution: [cell setNeedsLayout];

Answer (score 1):

have you tried doing something like this?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    cell.image = imgView.image;
});
```

or reloading using `- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths` like

```
[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:YourIndexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade SDWebImage, your version doesn't work with iOS8.
Download the last library of SDWebImage and use sd_setImageWithURL method instead.